# Google Analytics API V4 and Management API V3

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have been updating the `Google Analytics Core Reporting API from V3 to V4` recently. Our application uses the Management API V3 and earlier it was running with the V3 of Analytics API. Now that I am updating Analytics Reporting API, how do I integrate the older version of this API with the latest version of Analytics API?

Is this even possible to run both of them together where Analytics is running on V4 and Management is running on V3.
I tried to do it but V3 of Management API complains about the Google.API version to not be matching its requirements.

I am trying to do this in dotnet. Let me know if you need any other information.

Snippet from the google analytics documentation:

[image: A snippet from the google documentation]

Comment: Can you give me the link to were you got that picture from that doesn't make any sense need to have the team look at that.   Its not going to require a separate library.  It will require different methods within the same library

Comment: @DaImTo https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Comment: I have logged this as a bug and I am going to ping the team about it sorry for any confusion this may have caused https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69091435

Answer (score 3):

The [Google Analytics core reporting API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) was replaced by the [Google Analytics Reporting API (v4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).  You can technically run both of them in different scripts, but some of the dimensions and metrics only work in v4 and wont work in v3.   Both of these APIs allow you to access your Google Analytics data.

The [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) is a standalone API used for Accessing the account information of Google Analytics it has nothing to do with accessing the Actual Google analytics data.   There is no new version of this API so nothing for you to be upgrading.

Note: You will need to include the reporting API scope in your client on Google developer console as well as the analytics API if you want to use both.
I think the management API still falls under the analytics API scope so your still going to need that even if you enable the reporting api

Comment: Yes exactly the issues that I was facing was that I needed the library for both versions in order to run the latest reporting api and management api since latest version of analytics api does not have any support for the management api.

Comment: Its just a single library the methods are just different.   Which language are you using?

Comment: I am doing this in dotnet.

Comment: you will need both of these packages to access both managment api and the reporting api https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4/  and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/  It is technically the same library just two different packages as we dont force you to download everything when you just want to access one api